# LWP::Simple getstore does not work in Windows

Tags: perl, lwp

As a part of my Perl script I have the following simple command which is supposed to download a `$url` and store its contents to a file `$file`:

```
getstore("$url", "$file");
```

This works perfectly fine when I run it on my fedora Linux, however when I run the same code on Windows, it seems that the `$file` remains empty..

This is very strange since, as I mentioned, there was no change to the code and this command is very basic.

Maybe anyone has a clue why such behavior might occur?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using as the filename?

Comment: Are you checking the status returned by getstore?  It looks like HTTP::Status is exported along with it so I think you should be able to store the code and then call status_message( $code )

Comment: I tried the following: `my $status = getstore("$url", "$file"); print "$status\n";` As a result the status is `500`, though I am not sure what it means.

Comment: 500 is Internal Server Error.

Comment: What exactly is the URL you're testing with?

Comment: @choroba, Normally, yes, but LWP does use codes in the 500 block to indicate some client errors, possibly including file creation errors. I don't know if it uses 500 specifically, though.

Comment: Again I would like to emphasize that the same code works fine on Linux  fedora platform, however I am not sure that it has something to do with read/write permissions since I see(in sniffer) that no HTTP GET is being issued at all..

Comment: Is your Windows machine behind a proxy by any chance?

Comment: Also, might it be worth using get rather than getstore while testing so that you can confirm whether the issue is with accessing the data or writing the file?

Comment: I am having the same problems with `LWP::Simple` on Windows, I get a 500 warning after a long timeout. It also seems to affect `ppm` from ActivePerl and the `cpan` installer, which I assume may be using this or similar modules.

Comment: @nick I think proxy is the culprit, but as my machine uses automatic detection, and I fail to find anything helpful on google, I've no idea how to find out how to get hold of the proxy server name. You have any idea?

Comment: Is it configured via a PAC file?

Comment: @Nick It's windows. I have no idea how it works. I am guessing DHCP has something to do with it.

Comment: @Nick I tried the same with simple "get" and it seems fine so I guess it's not an issue with proxy. I have no idea what is the problem to do the same with "getstore". Anyway I think I'm going to stick with "get" for now. Thanks!

Comment: if you do print $file does it look right?  If you switched from something like /usr/file.txt to c:\user\file.txt then perl will see the \ as escapes so you need to either use "c:\\user\\file.txt" or 'c:\user\file.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Finding a proxy quite easy sometimes:

Try to open a nonexisting webpage and most of time the PROXY reports an error and print out its own details.

Try this: -.ds.com
Check the line: Your web proxy is:....